# Doubts about the use of Cross-Validation in GLMM

Tags: r, logistic, lme4-nlme, glmm, ecology

I've recently ask in statckoverflow about some doubts with logistic regression fitted with a GLMM and an user recommend me asking in this forum. So, here it goes.

I work with a wild population of a bird species in which we can find two different types of individuals: those with a subordinate status called floaters (birds with no territory which is secretevely moving inside the population) and those with a high status called territorials (birds that defend a territory, a partner and a nest). Our fieldwork procedure let us distinguish through their behavior between these two types of individuals and our currently question is if there are any morphological differences between floaters and territorial individuals.

For this aim, we have 7 cohorts of 1-year adults and its morphological data (weight, tarsus length (both to measure condition), length of ornamental feathers, amount spotted plumage... etc) to compare between floaters and territorials (F vs. T).

And I've built the following model after exploring and clearing up my data set: a logistic regression using lme4 with year as a random factor. After getting the results on the summary, I've checked the residuals using the package DHARMa and everything is ok.

```
logistic <- glmer(status ~ body_condition + plumage + feather_length + (1|year)
                   data = data, family = "binomial")

summary(logistic)

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: status ~ body_condition + mot_suma + feather_length + (1 | capture_year)
   Data: data2

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   239.4    255.2   -114.7    229.4      171 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.8357 -0.7930 -0.5998  1.0149  2.2089 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 capture_year (Intercept) 0.1558   0.3947  
Number of obs: 176, groups:  capture_year, 6

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)    -1.89970    2.01301  -0.944  0.34532   
body_condition -0.51050    0.18749  -2.723  0.00647 **
mot_suma       -0.46016    1.10950  -0.415  0.67833   
feather_length  0.04145    0.05569   0.744  0.45668   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) condtn mot_sm
body_condi   0.179              
mot_suma    -0.081 -0.057       
fethr_lngth -0.991 -0.177  0.064
```

**My question is**: after getting my model and check its residuals, is it needed to do any other type of evaluation/checking to present these results in a manuscript?

I ask this because I think I've been messing some concepts. I learned about the k-fold cross validation method, but I am not sure that it is indicated for what I am doing since I am not interested in predicting the status of new birds in a feature, I've only wanted to know if there were any morphological differences (but instead of doing a model for each variable, I've built a logistic regression including all together).

Could you help me clarify these concepts? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: If your question is about 'morphological differences between floaters and territorial individuals', it might be more 'natural' to consider each morphological metric as response variable and bird status as an explanatory variable, don't you think? And perform several ANOVA or Multivariate ANOVA ?


Unless those morphological metrics drive their behaviour, in which case your question might need to be reformulated. Sorry I'm not really answering your question... To me checking residuals as well as heterogeneity issues etc. is enough for this kind of analysis

Comment: @Circuspygargus hi!! Thank you for your response. Yes, indeed, at the beginning we had doubts about which would be the best type of analysis. But in our case, our hypothesis is that individuals in better condition, longer ornamental feathers etc would increase the status of individuals. So, you are right, I guess I should reformulate my question. Thanks! Food for thought!

Comment: You're welcome! You should read [this book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387874579) which is very instructive about Mixed Models and their validation.